# Can't scroll to all the way to top of absolute/centered div when taller than viewport

Tags: html, css

I've created a centered div with position: absolute/top: 50%/left: 50%/transform: translate(-50%, -50%) css properties on my website, but now, when there is more content and the div height exceeds the viewport height, I'm able to scroll to the very bottom, but not the very top of it anymore. Ths vertically narrower the viewport, the more of the top of the div overflows beyond the page with no way to reach it. Is there a way to fix this?

My code

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>some title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- further Meta tags -->
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="content">
            some content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.main {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border: .5rem solid red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 1rem;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
```

*Note: some of the content is dynamically generated by a JS script, but I've tested it, and the same problem occurs with static content only.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this solution right for you (see the demo below)?

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;                     /* ! */
    height: auto;                         /* ! */
    
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.main {
    /*
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    */
    
    /* ! */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    
    text-align: center;
    border: .5rem solid red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 50vh;                     /* ! */
    height: auto;                         /* ! */
}

.content {
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>some title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- further Meta tags -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam bibendum tristique ipsum nec viverra. Morbi lacus justo,
      dictum quis consequat vitae, dapibus et sem. Phasellus leo nulla, elementum congue dui id, vulputate porttitor erat. In
      hac habitasse platea dictumst. Etiam feugiat, felis ac luctus luctus, elit arcu consectetur elit, sed volutpat quam nisi
      vitae lorem. Nunc libero dolor, scelerisque id lorem a, rhoncus faucibus nibh. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique
      senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris sit amet blandit metus. Duis ut pretium nisl.
      
      Integer tincidunt dui in cursus cursus. Morbi sed lobortis erat. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris eget gravida ex. Phasellus
      eu gravida libero, id porttitor orci. Maecenas id auctor ex. Vestibulum nec lorem leo. Nulla eget quam id ante fermentum
      convallis eget posuere lectus. Nulla placerat pharetra lorem id sagittis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipiscing elit. Fusce pulvinar felis cursus massa auctor, sit amet condimentum libero iaculis.
      
      Nunc rhoncus molestie sem. Vivamus nec quam augue. Proin auctor eros eu vehicula rutrum. Aliquam lacinia tincidunt
      mauris at pretium. Vestibulum eu metus vel nunc tempor vulputate. Nullam interdum efficitur iaculis. Nulla pulvinar,
      erat vel placerat pretium, mi enim semper dolor, et tempor ipsum magna non mauris. Mauris ac dignissim nunc, quis
      egestas nunc. Nunc ac pulvinar lectus, ac ornare dolor. Etiam viverra odio a sapien consequat molestie. Morbi ex dui,
      porta sit amet malesuada quis, hendrerit at nulla.
      
      Morbi sagittis tempor lorem, quis suscipit augue dictum vitae. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per
      conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec facilisis diam sit amet rhoncus tincidunt. Nullam finibus metus nibh,
      vitae euismod risus dapibus vel. Vivamus vehicula risus at scelerisque interdum. Quisque nec mi metus. In finibus justo
      nec purus maximus, non condimentum mauris ullamcorper.
      
      Suspendisse et lorem neque. Nunc egestas ullamcorper est, ut mattis arcu iaculis ac. Aenean vehicula, ipsum non volutpat
      sollicitudin, nisi leo maximus elit, ac consectetur mi nisi ac turpis. Vivamus cursus, dui id facilisis fringilla,
      tellus est maximus tellus, ac euismod purus velit ut massa. Maecenas auctor, turpis at semper auctor, massa lorem
      hendrerit lectus, et semper tellus tortor ut diam. Praesent nulla lectus, fermentum id rhoncus ac, imperdiet et ex. Nunc
      consectetur interdum mi vel tincidunt. Curabitur ac suscipit lorem. Sed accumsan pellentesque quam, ut imperdiet velit
      sollicitudin id. Aliquam quis vestibulum neque. Praesent pretium purus nec felis euismod convallis. Morbi sit amet
      pretium augue, ut commodo sem. Fusce mattis nisi a mi condimentum, in vehicula tortor dignissim. Duis ipsum ex, suscipit
      sit amet lobortis vel, fringilla sed odio. Maecenas sodales purus nec lectus sodales ullamcorper. Sed convallis eros
      dui.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for the quick answer! I'd actually like the .main div to still vertically rezise to fit the content instead of the content scrolling inside of it. 
I've also clarified the question to make more clear that that's what I'm looking for.